# Ratio of lesser to greater common tangents (for 2 non-intersecting circles outside each other admitting 4 common tangents).

Tags: geometry

If c is the distance between the centers, a and b the radii of the two circles, the square of the ratio of the lesser to the greater common tangent is given by $\frac{c^2 - (a + b)^2}{c^2 - (a - b)^2}$. The diagram below demonstrates this (x and y are the greater and lesser common tangents, respectively), but can anyone give the proof of this relationship?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two diagrams:
[image: C1]
[image: C2]

This demonstrates that the length of the outside tangent is $\sqrt{D^2-(R-r)^2}$, while the length or the inside tangent is $\sqrt{D^2-(R+r)^2}$.

Hence the the ratio of the squares of these tangents is

$$\frac{D^2-(R+r)^2}{D^2-(R-r)^2}$$

as desired.